# Set slave_exec_mode value for RDS

Tags: mysql, replication, amazon-rds, master-slave-replication

I am trying to figure out a way to set `slave_exec_mode` to `idempotent` on Amazon RDS.

I've checked the parameters associated with created DB instance on Amazon Console, but this parameter is not exit with other ones.

Is there a way to set it through command-line?

Comment: Possible red flag.  On a correctly populated and configured replica, there is typically no need to change this value.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I am trying to overcome `Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND;`

Comment: That error should only ever happen if you deliberately created an environment where it's anticipated. Otherwise, it indicates problems that you need to find and resolve. [*"For storage engines other than NDB, IDEMPOTENT mode should be used only when you are absolutely sure that duplicate-key errors and key-not-found errors can safely be ignored. It is meant to be used in fail-over scenarios for NDB Cluster where multi-master replication or circular replication is employed, and is not recommended for use in other cases."*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html)

Comment: Is this a standard, managed RDS replica of an RDS master?  Or something more custom?  Did you make the replica writable and then run queries against it that changed the data?

Comment: RDS used as slave for external - on premises - mysql master. Using `MIXED` binlog replication.

Comment: This suggests that either you did not use the `--single-transaction` option for `mysqldump` when creating the dump file applied to the replica, or that you didn't specify `--master-data=2` and capture the correct binlog coordinates from comment automatically added at the beginning of the dump file, when configuring the RDS machine to begin replication.  Either oversight would result in a replica that begins in a state that is inconsistent with the master.

Comment: I used the `--single-transaction` option but not `--master-data=2` , the only thing that I have to mention here is that I did the `mysqldump` and I have to solve this issue [Without downtime].

Comment: If you didn't use `--master-data=2` then how did you get the correct binlog coordinates?  There is no magic bullet, here.  You appear to have made an error when setting up replication and will need to do it over.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97144/discussion-between-eng7-and-michael-sqlbot).